# java run cp not being recognized

Tags: java, command-line, classpath

I have been trying too long to run a Java program in a server unsuccesfully. I run

```
java -cp bin:../../lib/*:../../bin/:lib/*: Test
```

and I get

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: edu/uci/ics/jung/graph/UndirectedSparseGraph
```

The class is in a .jar located in `lib/` and is requested by another class located in `../../lib`

The weird thing is that some of the classes from other jars in `lib/` are found. Only this particular one seems to be problematic. When I run it with Eclipse in my local it runs just fine.

Any idea what may be happening?

Thanks in advance

Solution:

No idea what happened. I just recompiled my jars.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting multiple jars in java classpath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath)

Comment: Hi, thanks but i am not sure it is the same, according to the question you cite my expression is well formed. Maybe something to do with interdependencies?

Comment: Have you tried putting all the jars in lib/ rather than scattered around?

Comment: yes, thanks I tried that but still no. It is a class in a jar which needs a class in another jar. Can this have something to do wuth the error?

Comment: Post the complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: The class "edu/uci/ics/jung/graph/UndirectedSparseGraph" is present in jung-graph-impl-2.0.jar. Please verify whether you have this jar in your lib folder?

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot @Jayaprasad but it is there. I just solved it by recompiling the jar